# How to query a database from a snaplet

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

My application is defined as:

```
data App = App { _api :: Snaplet Api, _db :: Snaplet Postgres }

makeLenses ''App

instance HasPostgres (Handler b App) where
    getPostgresState = with db get
    setLocalPostgresState s = local (set (db . snapletValue) s)
```

where `_api` is a snaplet I am creating. It is defined as:

```
data Api = Api
```

I would now like to use `query_` function inside the `Api` snaplet. The only way I can do so is to define `Api` as `data Api = Api { _db :: Snaplet Postgres }`, but it seems that this will initialise postgres snaplet twice, which I don't think is right. I'm not sure how to get `_db` from the 'parent' `App` either.

Am I on the right path here? What's the correct way to access the database in the `Api` snaplet?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating this `Api` snaplet?  Are you reusing the things in `Api` across two or more web apps?  If not, I would recommend not using a snaplet.  Then everything will work perfectly.  `Handler App App` will have a `HasPostgres` instance and you can go on your merry way.

Comment: The main reason is to serve APIs from `/api/...` URL. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `dir "api" apiHandler`  (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.0.0/docs/Snap-Core.html#v:dir)

Comment: Or, with the [route function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.0.0/docs/Snap-Core.html#v:route)...`route [("api", apiHandler), ...other routes here...]`